# 301 redirect with GET variables

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect, get

Good morning all,

When I do a search for the name of my site on google I end up with lots of links like mysite.com/?page=1
mysite.com/?page=2
Etc.

I would like to redirect 301 of these links which ends in mysite.com/?page=X
to monsite.com
Because I am afraid that Google will see it as duplicate content knowing that it displays all the home page of my site ...

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=1(&|$) [NC] 

RewriteRule ^(mysite)/?$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

which doesn't work on my side.

Could you help me ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only. `mysite` is not part of the path component of the example “URL” you have shown.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, and that is exactly why the OP uses a `RewriteCond` to test for the query part.

Comment: Your question is unclear... Please invest some more effort into revising your question. There is an "edit" link below your question, _use it_ ... You write: "I have the same problem" ... the same as what? You write that your page is referenced... why is that an issue? What does "doesn't work" actually mean? Why would you want to use rewriting to handle wrong references to your site?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I have edited my message. My english is not perfect sorry.

Comment: @arkascha I was referring to `RewriteRule ^(mysite)/?$`, in connection with the given example `mysite.com/?page=1`

Answer (score 0):

To redirect such requests this should be what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)page=\d+(?:&|$) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?$ / [QSD,R=301,END]
```

Or a more general example which preserves given a path

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)page=\d+(?:&|$) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,END]
```

Keep in mind however that even with such redirection you still have the issue that somewhere those references are generated. Google does not make them up. So to fix the actual issue and not just a symptom you will have to find the actual issue...

Comment: Hello, I tested your directives in my htaccess but they don't work.
I have read elsewhere that it was not possible to redirect on variables in GET ...

Comment: Well, there is no redirect from my mysite.com/?page=2 url to mysite.com

Comment: The rules will work for that URL you mention. Could it be that you are looking at a cached result?